# Getting Socket Exception in every few minutes on hitting other server through restTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
17-03-2022 11:55:43.994 \u001b[35m[http-nio-8080-exec-6]\u001b[0;39m \u001b[36m\u001b[0;39m \u001b[34mINFO \u001b[0;39m 
c.b.m.d.handler.DynamicQrApiHandler.startTransaction(75) - Exception inside startTransaction for terminalId 0376513U, 
Exception is I/O error on POST request for \"https://api.bharatpe.in/external/pos/collect/startTxn\": Connection reset; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset, 
stack [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:784), 
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:710), 
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:601), 
com.bharatswipeswitch.module.dynamicQr.handler.DynamicQrApiHandler.startTransaction(DynamicQrApiHandler.java:67),
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the logs on the server you are calling, it looks like it stops responding, or is forcefully closing down the connection.

An unstable network may also cause this type of exceptions to occur.